# Virtual Machine Manager not showing edit XML option

Tags: virtualization, kvm-virtualization, qemu, xml

I'm looking to use my virtual machine manager to setup a Windows KVM/QEMI. I followed this tutorial...

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2WDASJ0ye0A

It's for Arch Linux but I managed to do it. I'm stuck on 7 minutes and 20 seconds. When he goes to KVM manager > Edit > Preferences. I only have the first option available (Enable Sytem Tray Icon).

The other two options...

Enable XML Editing
Enable libguestfs VM introspection

...are not there. I tried upading kvm but I still cant get the option to edit the XML.

Comment: What Ubuntu version are you on and what is your virt-manager version ($ dpkg -l virt-manager). AFAIK it is a feature of >=v2.2 and therefore >=Ubuntu 20.04.