# kvm does not have the XML option

Tags: 18.04, kvm-virtualization

I need to properly set up a kvm using XML which should've been a feature except that i couldn't find it on my system as following:
[image]

While it should've been like this:
[image]

[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288020/virtual-machine-manager-not-showing-edit-xml-option) is a very similar issue to mine and when i tried what he asked, this was the output:

```
$ dpkg -l virt-manager
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name                   Version          Architecture     Description
+++-======================-================-================-==================================================
ii  virt-manager           1:1.5.1-0ubuntu1 all              desktop application for managing virtual machines
```

What should i do to upgrade it to 2.2 (if this is the solution)?

Comment: Would something like this work for you? `virsh edit desk-ii` where `desk-ii` is the name of the VM you want to edit the .xml file for.

Comment: @DougSmythies actually, The tutorial i am following requires doing lot more, in cpu and such so your advice will help in this only particular case.